What are your thoughts on P=NP
While it is possible that P does or does not equal NP, I would love to hear the philosopher's ideas on the matter. This is a mathematics question in which we are asked if certain problems can be reduced algorithmically to basic polynomial functions, these problems being considered currently solvable although inefficiently due to a lack of objectively reasonable pathing.
Consider this problem which is noted as "P=NP" complete, often called the summation problem.
You give a set of numbers to a computer and request that it tell you if a combination of these numbers exists that would sum to a particular target value.
In the first set [1,3,5,8,9,14,16] with a target value of [30] The computer is capable of finding the answer [yes, 16 and 14] within moments, regardless of the algorithmic process you have chosen to undertake in order to drive it and get the results.
However consider a second list [1,13,16,74,23,98,76,56,45,34,52,1,2,2,3,4,5,98,09,8,7,5,4]
with repeats and a lack of order the process of determining which values may or may not add up to a target value becomes significantly more difficult. You can extrapolate here and save me the time in creating a third list that consists of a thousand terms This is the heart of an NP algorithm. No current function or series of functions can produce results that we could reliably call the most efficient route to answering this question.
Many argue that this problem is inherently unsolvable and that there are simply problems such as these where we will not be able to solve our issue in polynomial time. Proving it either way is considered answering one of the world's most difficult math problems.
What are your thoughts, can P=NP be solved?

"What are your thoughts?" questions are off-topic on this site. A philosophical discussion of significance of P = NP can be found in SEP:"(i) P≠NP is widely believed to be true on the basis of convergent inductive and heuristic evidence; (ii) we currently have no reason to suspect that this statement is formally independent of the mathematical theories which we accept in practice; but (iii) a proof P≠NP is still considered to be beyond the reach of current techniques."

But still do feel welcome at this site. Browse around a bit to see what kind of questions this site is good for.

If only we had a function that gives the answer. I'm guessing that functions and algorithms are inherently different kinds of things. Can we prove that instead? Does it need proving?

At an informal level, it would seem bizarre to suppose that P=NP since it would entail that for every problem that can be solved with an NP algorithm there exists a P algorithm that solves it, but nobody has been able to find it.
